# Edit EBCDIC file format

Tags: unix, aix, ebcdic

I am testing a Data services job which takes an EBCDIC encoded file as an input.
I need to edit some data for testing purposes. I can read the file through RFHUtil utility but can't edit it.

Is it possible to edit it through an windows editor or any unix utitlity?

Comment: Program `iconv` might be able to convert it to ascii. Mind you, there is more than one EBCDIC, depending on the vendor (IBM, Siemens, Tandem etc)

Comment: I saw the man page for iconv initially but then later on went on to use dd command which seemed easier. dd -if filename_input -of filename_output conv=ascii. It seems to have worked for me.

Comment: Many Java Editor's e.g. jEdit can handle EBCDIC (use a font of IBM037 or CP037 for US EBCDIC). They will have trouble if there are no \n characters (e.g. Fixed width file).